# React Native birthday picker - componentWillREceiveProps

Tags: react-native, picker, componentwillreceiveprops

I need to build a birthday picker for a react naive application. I found the following https://github.com/ericmorgan1/react-native-birthday-picker but it has the deprecated method componentWillREceiveProps

Im not that experienced yet, so i don't know how to change this to the new methods to make it work. Can anyone help?

```
//
// DatePicker with an optional year.
//
// code from https://github.com/ericmorgan1/react-native-birthdaypicker/blob/master/BirthdayPicker.js


import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Picker, } from 'react-native';

export default class BirthdayPicker extends React.Component {
static defaultProps= {
selectedYear:   (new Date()).getFullYear(),     // Year to initialize the picker to (set to 0 to not have a year)
selectedMonth:  (new Date()).getMonth(),        // Month to initialize the picker to
selectedDay:    (new Date()).getDate(),         // Day to initailize the picker to
yearsBack:      100,                            // How many years backwards (from starting year) you want to show

onYearValueChange: function(year, idx) { },     // Function called when year changes
onMonthValueChange: function(month, idx) { },   // Function called when month changes
onDayValueChange: function(day, idx) { },       // Function called when day changes
}

constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.startingYear = this.props.selectedYear;
this.state = {
  year:     this.props.selectedYear,
  month:    this.props.selectedMonth, 
  day:      this.props.selectedDay,
}
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
this.setState({
  year: nextProps.selectedYear, month: nextProps.selectedMonth, day: nextProps.selectedDay
});
}

// Tries to get the browser locale...
getLocale() {
if (navigator.language) { return navigator.language; }
if (navigator.languages && navigator.languages.length > 0) { return navigator.languages[0]; }
return "en-us"; // Default to English
}

// Loops through the months and gets the long name string...
 getMonthNames() {
 var locale = this.getLocale();

var monthNames = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  var date = new Date(2000, i, 15);
  monthNames.push(date.toLocaleString(locale, { month: "long" }));
}
return monthNames;
}

// Returns the number of days in the given month...
getNumDaysInMonth(year, month) {
// February is the only month that can change, so if there's no year, assume it has the maximum (29) days...
return (year == 0 && month == 1) ? 29 : (new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate());
}

// Returns the <Picker.Item> values for the years...
renderYearPickerItems() {
// If year was 0, change it to current...
var currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
var centerYear = this.startingYear;
if (centerYear === 0) { centerYear = currentYear; }

// Set starting and ending years...
var startYear = centerYear - this.props.yearsBack;
var endYear = currentYear;

var years = [];
for (var i = startYear; i <= endYear; i++) {
  years.push(<Picker.Item label={i.toString()} value={i} key={i} />);
}
years.push(<Picker.Item label="----" value={0} key={0} />);
return years;
}

// Returns the <Picker.Item> values for the months...
renderMonthPickerItems() {
var months = this.getMonthNames();
return months.map(function(month, index) {
  return <Picker.Item label={month} value={index} key={index} />;
});
}

// Returns the <Picker.Item> values for the days (based on current month/year)...
renderDayPickerItems() {
// February is the only day that can change, so if there's no year, assume it has the maximum (29) days...
var numDays = this.getNumDaysInMonth(this.state.year, this.state.month);

var days = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= numDays; i++) {
    days.push(<Picker.Item label={i.toString()} value={i} key={i} />);
}
return days;
}

// Occurs when year value changes...
onYearChange = (value, index) => {
// Check if days are valid...
var maxDays = this.getNumDaysInMonth(value, this.state.month);
var day = (this.state.day > maxDays) ? maxDays : this.state.day;

this.setState({ year: value, day: day });
this.props.onYearValueChange(value, index);
}

// Occurs when month value changes...
onMonthChange = (value, index) => {
// Check if days are valid...
var maxDays = this.getNumDaysInMonth(this.state.year, value);
var day = (this.state.day > maxDays) ? maxDays : this.state.day;

this.setState({ month: value, day: day });
this.props.onMonthValueChange(value, index);
}

// Occurs when day value changes...
onDayChange = (value, index) => {
this.setState({ day: value });
this.props.onDayValueChange(value, index);
}

render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Picker style={styles.monthPicker} selectedValue={this.state.month} onValueChange={this.onMonthChange}>
      {this.renderMonthPickerItems()}
    </Picker>

    <Picker style={styles.dayPicker} selectedValue={this.state.day} onValueChange={this.onDayChange}>
      {this.renderDayPickerItems()}
    </Picker>

    <Picker style={styles.yearPicker} selectedValue={this.state.year} onValueChange={this.onYearChange}>
      {this.renderYearPickerItems()}
    </Picker>
  </View>
  );
  }
 }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container:    { flexDirection: "row", },
monthPicker:  { flex: 3, },
dayPicker:    { flex: 1, },
yearPicker:   { flex: 2, },
});
```